# Org todo list: Filter regexp

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, regular-expressions

When I press `C-c a M` and search for a certain tag, I get a todo list of all open tasks for this specific tag.

Is it now possible to do a regular expression search similar to the sparse-tree regular expression search, for example:

```
+DEADLINE<"<today>"
```

?

Somehow it does not work for me, when i try that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works, at least with org 9.1.9, but it can be slow on large and/or many files.

For example, with the `x.org` file

```
** TODO one
   DEADLINE: <2018-04-10 Tue>
** TODO two
   DEADLINE: <2018-04-09 Mon>
```

as current buffer and today `<2018-04-09>`, the command `C-c a < M` (restricting the search to the current buffer) gives

```
Headlines with TAGS match: DEADLINE="<today>"
Press ‘C-u r’ to search again with new search string
  x:          TODO two
```

or

```
Headlines with TAGS match: +DEADLINE>"<today>"
Press ‘C-u r’ to search again with new search string
  x:          TODO one
```

depending on which of those two match strings you enter.